# Best way to communicate between 2 processes in UNIX: One running a ruby server and other C++ client

Tags: c++, ruby, ipc

I need my C++ client code communicating with a ruby server code running on the same box. There are multiple ways to do it I guess, what I am looking for is what might be the safest and easiest way to do this.

I am planning to use a UNIX socket with the client side C++ communicating using Boost asio. But writing all the async connect handlers makes me wonder, what if, just what if there's a connection failure or something? Having a error handler for every conceivable situation is beyond me (I am a mere mortal).

So what do you think of what's the best way to have these processes communicating with each other safely?

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, you are going to have to deal with connection problems no matter what: you are building a distributed system, so all [Fallacies of Distributed Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_Distributed_Computing) are yours to enjoy.

However, you can eliminate lots of the headaches by using something that encapsulates a whole lot of the problems for you.  Message transport toolkits, when used on both sides of the connection, can deal with a lot of the headaches around robust communication for you.

[0mq](http://www.zeromq.org/) is a fairly light toolkit that adds a robust framing and transmission mechanism over sockets, so provided both sides can use those tools, you gain substantial benefits.

You might also find that an external queue solution like Redis, or a shared SQL database, provide benefits - while you still have to face down connection problems, you have reduced the number of additional things to solve.

Ultimately, though, you can't avoid connection problems.  Everything can fail, no matter how robust.  After all, the Ruby server could crash due to a bug in Ruby or something, or be administratively stopped at any time - and short of running your C++ and Ruby code in the same process, nothing can prevent that, so you just have to deal with it.

Comment: +1 for 0mq. I am looking at a scheme that doesn't require additional gems or rpms or tarballs for the moment though.